# PHP <? ?> code turns to <!--? ?-->

Tags: php, html, comments

I built a local server with WAMP and moved the data from the web server.

However, the PHP code mixed in the middle of the HTML is turning into an HTML comment by itself.

```
<?php
    code.. // this block works just fine.
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
<body>
<? include 'a/file/navbar.php'; ?> <-- it turns below.
<!--? include 'a/file/navbar.php'; ?--!>
```

It works well on the web server, so it is doubtful whether there is any difference in the PHP settings between the environment of the web server and the local server.

Comment: Please use <?php ?> instead of only <? ?>.

Comment: tried. it's also not work..

Comment: Are you sure the php config file is setup to use <? ?>

Comment: "turning into an HTML comment by itself" — Not by itself. You're looking at it  in a DOM inspector, the browser is doing that in an attempt to recover from the error when it gets PHP source code when it is expecting HTML.

Comment: ah..... thanks all. it works after version switch to php5 and switch again to 7. ...and don't know why;